# Spring repository components not found in gradle subproject (Springboot)

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a multi project gradle project:

ht-java

- ht-domain
- ht-scraper

ht-scraper uses the domain model and daos which are located in ht-domain.
when i start the springboot app i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hypetube.domain.dao.ChannelRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

when i have the repository classes within ht-scraper everything works fine.

my spring app looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.hypetube", "com.hypetube.domain"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties //use this to register other properties sources e.g. property files
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void printActiveSpringProfiles() {
        log.info("Following spring profiles are active: {}", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles())));
    }
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include 'ht-domain', 'ht-scraper'
```

build.gradle (ht.scraper):

```
compile project(":ht-domain")
```

Everything works as it should; The project compiles no errors are imminent.
Just when i start the app the error occurs.

Comment: Is that project available online?

Comment: unfortunately not, its a commercial project. i cant publish it all. could it be that it is an issue with the manifest of the subproject jar? the manifest is currently empty

Comment: Maybe it can, difficult to say. If possible provide sample project that reproduces error.

Comment: did so https://github.com/dasAnderl/ht-java

Comment: if you execute the tests youll get the error.
if you move PlaylistRepository to ht-sraper everything will work just fine.
in my original project the spring data repositories werent even annotated and it worked when residing in ht-scraper. in ht-domain it cant be even found when annotated (@component, @Repository etc)

Comment: Great will have a look later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very strange why `spring-boot` plugin doesn't include the `ht-domain` subproject. To workaround tests add the following piece of code to `ht-scraper/build.gradle`

```
test {
    classpath = project(":ht-domain").sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But there's still problem with running packaged application. I've removed all the annotations from `PlaylistRepository` class and added the following annotation to `Application`:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories({"com.hypetube.domain"})
```

No it starts well - at least there're no classpath issues. Hope that helps somehow and as I said quite weird behavior :/

Comment: this seems to work. instead of using @EnableMongoRepositories, ill use project(":ht-domain").sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath in the compile dependencies instead. thx to Opal

Comment: That also should to do the job. Nevertheless quite strange behavior.

Comment: yes, you are right. i think something is buggy, probably in springboot.

Comment: @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
is still needed even if project(":ht-domain").sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath in compile deps....weird